# Hover/focus state activated initially on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, expand, pageload

I have a module that shows/hides content when engaged with via hover or focus states.

I want to have the hidden content within the first section visible when you first arrive on the page, and then once a user engages with the module, have its current functionality take over.

I've tried to isolate this section via the CSS using `.color:first-child` -- You'll notice a red border around the section that I'd like expanded on page load within the codepen below.

https://codepen.io/ckatz/pen/XQaKdB

Is this something that can be accomplished solely in CSS, or would JS or JQuery need to be employed?

Answer (score 2):

You could create an 'active' class with the same styles as the hover classes and apply it only to the first one, but it would not be removed upon interaction with the module. You could use sibling selectors to overwrite them *while* the other divs are focused/hovered, but it would revert when the user goes somewhere else.  Ultimately you'd need JS to detect that something had been hovered/clicked and remove the styles permanently.

```
.color:hover, .color.active {
    /* Change the flex-basis so that we know what
    size to transition to on hover. Arbitrary,
    based on our design/content.
  */
    flex-basis: 20em;
}

.color:hover .details, .color.active .details {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

And some JS that detects mouseover to remove the class, but you could use clicks and/or whatever other events you deem necessary:

```
const module = document.getElementsByClassName('color-list')[0];
module.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  const firstBox = document.getElementsByClassName('light-brown-55')[0];
  firstBox.classList.remove('active');
})
```

I made a working fork [here](https://codepen.io/extrachrisb/pen/byVvjy)